# Сократить обращение к singleton классу

Tags: c++, классы, singleton

У меня в программе есть singleton класс, к объекту которого я обращаюсь как `my_class::instance().metod(...)`

Возможно ли эту запись сократить, не меняя имён класса/методов?

`typedef my_class::instance() a;` который я попробовал, не является правильным т.к. my_class::instance() - объект, а не тип (Появляется соответствующая ошибка)

```
my_class& my_class::instance()
{
    static my_class single;
    return single;
}
```

Или для такого нужно по другому реализовывать класс? Просто это самая простая реализация singleton класса, которую я нашёл

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ¿А что вы тут собираетесь сокращать и с какой целью? От имени класса и названия метода никак не избавиться.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант первый — если все эти вызовы в одной области видимости, ввести переменную-ссылку наподобие

```
myclass& M = myclass::instance();
```

и дальше просто работать с `M.method()` и иже с ним.

Вариант второй — воспользоваться препроцессором, типа

```
#define M myclass::instance()
...
M.method();
```

Comment: Спасибо, второй способ помог, а первый мне не везде можно применить т.к. конструктор класса я сделал приватным (забыл написать)

Comment: А это никак не мешает. Я же четко указал *ссылку*, видите `&` в `myclass& M`? Здесь конструктор не нужен.

Comment: @Евгений Второй способ вам совсем не поможет, так как название макроса должно получится еще длиннее, чем название класса + название метода.

Comment: @user7860670 а почему длиннее-то? Вроде в предложенном варианте имя макроса - всего одна буква...

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Для макросов следует использовать глобально-уникальные идентификаторы во избежание коллизии со сторонним кодом. т.е. что-то вроде `MY_COMPANY_MY_PROJECT_OUTER_NAMESPACE_INNER_NAMESPACE_MY_CLASS_GET_INSTANCE`. Идентификаторы из одной буквы вообще не очень хорошая идея, а уж макросы и подавно. Это треш из олимпиадного программирования и от любителей экономить на байтах.

Comment: @user7860670 вообще, я в курсе. Но работать это будет и цель - сократить запись - будет достигнута. На сколько это хорошо или плохо с точки зрения читаемости кода, сопровождаемости, вероятности коллизий и т.д. - другой вопрос. Вы же говорили "не поможет", а не "не надо так делать, это плохое решение"

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов А плохое решение помочь не может в принципе. Собственно а в чем у вас заключается исходная проблема - так и осталось неизвестным.

Comment: @user7860670 тут я с Вами не соглашусь. Плохое решение - все равно решение, если поставленная цель достигнута. Стоит ли им пользоваться - это уже другой вопрос, ответ на него зависит от очень многих факторов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131776/discussion-between---and-user7860670).

Comment: Блин, только не макрос. Тогда уж глобальную функцию.